# How to display flash messages in rails service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, service-object

I want to add service objects in to my controller. Is there any chance to include flash messages in to this service object?

**user_stocks_controller**

```
class UserStocksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user_stock = UserStocksCreator.new(current_user, params).call
    redirect_to my_portfolio_path
  end
end
```

service objects **user_stocks_creator**

```
class UserStocksCreator
  def initialize(current_user, params)
    @current_user = current_user
    @params = params[:stock_ticker]
  end

  def call
    stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params)
    if stock.blank?
      stock = Stock.new_from_lookup(params)
      stock.save
    end
    @user_stock = UserStock.create(user: current_user, stock: stock)
    flash[:success] = "Stock #{@user_stock.stock.name} was successfully added to portfolio"
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :current_user, :params
end
```

With this code I have an error:

> undefined local variable or method `flash'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flash` method is only available in the controller. When you want to set the flash in the service object then you need to pass the flash to the service object.

```
# in the controller
def create
  @user_stock = UserStocksCreator.new(current_user, params, flash).call
  redirect_to my_portfolio_path
end

# in the service
class UserStocksCreator
  def initialize(current_user, params, flash)
    @current_user = current_user
    @params = params[:stock_ticker]
    @flash = flash
  end

  def call
    # unchanged...
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :current_user, :params, :flash
end
```

Comment: Indeed! Thanks a million!